# Regex Find and Replace in MSVS 2008

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have a function I want to replace in this manner

myDictionary.Add("variable_key", "constant_value");

After replace, I want it to become

myDictionary.Add("variable_key", variable_key);

I tried to use

`Add("{[.]+}", "constant_value");`
replace to
`Add("\1", \1);`

But it cannot find the line. What am I missing? Please excuse me if this is a noob question. I always always have problems with regex. I just cannot understand them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` creates a character class, matching the literal characters between the brackets.
Therefore, `[.]` matches only the `.` character.

You want to write `.`, not inside of `[]`.

You also need to escape the parentheses with `\`.